Finding the hypervolume within two cylinders and 2 planes where z>0
I was presented with the following exercise: find the hypervolume under f(x,y,z)=z over the solid within the cylinders x^2 +z^2=1 and x^2 +z^2 =16, the planes x-y+z=-1 and x-y+z=-4 where z>0. I began integrating the first integral with respect to y and ended up with
∫(from 0 to 2pi) ∫(from 1 to 4) 3(r^2)cos(theta) dr d(theta).
My result was 0, but the answer posted says 126. I also tried:
∫(from 0 to pi/2) ∫(from 1 to 4) 3(r^2)cos(theta) dr d(theta)
Because of the “z>0” part of the exercise. I am not sure what to make of this part of the information given, which I realize is the part I am confused on. I turned to this platform since I was unsuccessful finding a similar exercise online.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.
